# upload data to server using json android

Tags: android, json

I need to upload data to server using json in android application.
This is the details provided to upload a comment.

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryZEhUiG82B2leVEc9 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Comment" 
Testing update
```

This is the coding which I have used to update.

```
URL url = new URL("MY URL comes here"); // here is your URL path
String js = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=Comment";
String id = "ID=1"; //need to mention the id for upload
String json = "testttting update";
JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();       
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setUseCaches(false);
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write(js.getBytes());
os.write(id.getBytes());
os.write(json.getBytes());
os.flush();
os.close();
```

There will be no response for this request. Only it will update to the server.
Kindly suggest me. I tried a lot and didn't find the solution.

Comment: How about using Volley?

Comment: I didnt used volley till now. Can you give the code how the code will change if you use volley?

Comment: `------WebKitFormBoundaryZEhUiG82B2leVEc9`. Yes. And where is it, your boundary?

Comment: @greenapps - Can you explain how to add this?

Comment: You can Google about it. Volley is most popular library for making HTTP conections to server. You can find several tutorials and links @paul

Comment: And i see no json in your code.

Comment: @MohammedAtif - Thanks for your information. I will google it and found. Can you explain is there any errors in this code?

Comment: @greenapps - Please suggest me, how to modify the code.

Comment: `This is the details provided to upload a comment.`. That does not match with sending json. So now what should you post?

Comment: @greenapps json object is name="Comment" and I need to give any comment like how we give comment to any post in facebook or linkedin. Here I gave "Testing update" is the comment I need to send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this to call post request**

```
 public class SendPostRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute(){}

        protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            try {

                URL url = new URL("MY URL comes here"); // here is your URL path

                JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();
                postDataParams.put("ID", "1");
                postDataParams.put("Name", "Chetan");

                Log.e("params",postDataParams.toString());

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(60000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(60000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();

                int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

                if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new
                            InputStreamReader(
                            conn.getInputStream()));

                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                    String line="";

                    while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                        sb.append(line);
                        break;
                    }

                    in.close();
                    return sb.toString();

                }
                else {
                    return new String("false : "+responseCode);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            /*In result you will get your response*/
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    public String getPostDataString(JSONObject params) throws Exception {

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;

        Iterator<String> itr = params.keys();

        while(itr.hasNext()){

            String key= itr.next();
            Object value = params.get(key);

            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(value.toString(), "UTF-8"));

        }
        return result.toString();
    }
```